# What are factors to take into consideration in choosing a programming language/paradigm for a rule-based natural-language translation program?

Tags: programming-languages

I have experience with object-oriented programming languages (C++ and Java), but I am wondering what kinds of programming languages — including OOP languages– or programming paradigms might be suitable for a rule-based natural-language translation program.

Does existing machine-translation software tend to use a certain paradigm or language?

Comment: You're _just_ doing translation? Going from say Japanese to the equivalent English in a general purpose environment?

Comment: Just translation unless I'm not thinking of something that most natural-language translation programs do. I was not contemplating languages with Asian characters.

Answer (score 3):

In all honesty: natural language translation is so *incredibly*, mindbogglingly, insanely, *hard* in general that the choice of language is completely and utterly irrelevant. Even when programming in [Malbolge](http://Wikipedia.Org/wiki/Malbolge), your 99.9999999% of your time, effort, resources, manpower and money is going to be spent *researching* and *inventing* the algorithms rather than implementing them.

There are basically two known approaches to machine translation that "work" (as in "produce results that are slightly better than *complete* garbage"): the classical approach and the Google approach:

- **classical approach**:

  1. hire a dozen or so researchers (alternatively: donate a couple of million dollars to a university)
  2. wait twenty years
- **Google approach**:

  1. create a database of everything ever written in the entire history of humankind
  2. pattern match your input text against documents where the same document was written in both the source and target language you want to translate from and to

There is also a third approach that IMO works best:

- use the Google Translate API

Now, if you insist on doing it yourself, then whenever you hear the words "rule-based", you should think of languages like [Prolog](http://Wikipedia.Org/wiki/Prolog) and [Mercury](https://MercuryLang.Org/) or embedded DSLs such as [KANREN](http://KANREN.SF.Net/) and [miniKANREN](http://miniKANREN.Org/).

Comment: Thanks. This is for learning purposes and not to produce something that would actually compete with existing software. I will read about the languages you mentioned.